# Não consigo passar os valores de uma página para outra com Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou com um problema no Laravel que não consigo resolver, e já tentei muitas coisas: O que quero é pegar os valores que estão em uma página e mandar para outra em um formulário.

O botão editar em uma lista tem o seguinte código:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('people.edit', $people) }}">{{ __('Editar') }}</a>
```

Essa é a rota:

```
Route::put('peoples', ['as' => 'peoples.edit', 'uses' => 'PeopleController@edit']);
```

Esse é o código no controlador

```
public function edit(People $people)
{
    return view('profilePeople.edit', compact('people'));
}
```

Esse é o código da classe

```
<?php namespace App; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class People extends Model { protected $table = 'people'; protected $fillable = ['name', 'email',]; protected $guarded = ['id']; }
```

Esse é o código onde um input onde deveria recuperar os valores passados.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Nome') }}" value="{{ old('name', $people->name) }}" required autofocus>
```

Não dá nenhum erro porém os valores não são passados.

Não sei se com essas informações alguém pode me ajudar, porém basta me mandar as informações que precisa e eu acrescentarei.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suas rotas:

```
// exibe a view com o formulario para editar a pessoa
Route::get('/peoples/{id}/edit', 'PeopleController@edit');
// atualiza a pessoa no banco de dados
Route::put('/peoples/{id}', 'PeopleController@update');
```

Seu botão:

```
<a href="{{ url('/peoples/' . $people->id . '/edit') }}">
    {{ __('Editar') }}
</a>
```

Seu controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $people = People::findOrFail($id);

    return view('profilePeople.edit', compact('people'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $people = People::findOrFail($id);

    try {
        DB::transaction(function() use ($data) {
            $people->update($data);
        });
    }catch(\Exception $exception){
        abort(500);
    }

    return redirect('/peoples/' . $id);
}
```

`profilePeople > edit.blade.php`

```
<form action="{{ url('/peoples/' . $people->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('put')

    <!-- Seus campos -->
</form>
```

Comment: Deu super certo! Eu quebrei tanto a cabeça e você resolveu isso tão rápido. Muito obrigado!